# How to write Definition 2.1. in texmaker?

Tags: typography

I am just want to write Defintion 2.1. in texmaker ? I already used

```
\subsection
\begin{definition}
\end{definition}
```

but I can't found the output Definition 2.1. so please kindly tell us.

After writing Definition 2.1 by followed the answer here. I'm want to write Remark 2.1. as given the below answer but my output is Remark 2.2. so please do help me to write Remark 2.1.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: You need to learn how to create theorems and in general, mathematical statements, take a look at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems), it could be helpful.

Comment: I am just want to write in systematic process in which texmaker give automatically subsection Definition 2.1, Definition 2.2 etc. Mr. Aranix

Comment: `\subsection` needs at least one argument, i.e. the subsection name. It can't be followed by a `\begin{definition}...\end{definition}`

Comment: Please kindly give me full command of it. How can we write Definition 2.1

Comment: Mr. @user114673 if you want to write mathematical statements in a systematic and automatic way, then you should understand first how the hierarchy macros works as well as Christian Hupfer notes. 

I clarify that Texmaker does not automatic, but `LaTeX` regardless of the editor (although I use Texmaker and I like a lot). You don't need a full (magic) command, is a full definition. Add a MWE and then will be easier to help you. Meanwhile please read the link above and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: If you now want numbered remarks, define a new theorem just as @harish showed you for definitions.

Comment: Please read some basic introductory material so you can understand how LaTeX works, use it more efficiently and improve the quality of your following questions.

Answer (score 9):

May be this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]    %% this does it
\begin{document}
  \section{Some}
  \section{some other}
  \begin{definition}
    Some definition
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]
\begin{document}
  \section{Some}
  \section{some other}
  \subsection{Some}
  \subsection{Other}
  \begin{definition}
    Some definition
  \end{definition}
  \begin{definition}
    Some other definition
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The usual way here to thank a [user] is by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).